# Elle n’en est pas à son premier geste - what do "elle" and "en" here refer to?

Tags: grammaire

> L'actrice américaine Sandra Bullock a fait don d'un million de dollars à la Croix-Rouge nippone. **Elle** n’**en** est pas à son premier geste. Sa première donation connue du grand public a été destinée aux familles des victimes et aux survivants de la tragédie du 11 Septembre.

I don't really understand what **elle** and **en** refer to in this sentence. Actually, the whole sentence is confusing to me. I'm not even sure what it's trying to say. It's obviously talking about some kind of gesture, but that's about all I can gather.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here *en* in *en être à* indicates a point in time, a moment (that has been reached so far).

Some examples :

- *J'en suis à la première étape de mon projet*. (I've reached the first stage of my project.)
- *J'en suis à mon premier voyage à Paris*. (This is the first trip I've ever made to Paris.)

*Geste* here refers to the donation and *elle* to the person who made the donation (*i.e.* Sandra Bullock).

You could rephrase the sentence with something like :

- Ce n'est pas le premier geste qu'elle fait (envers une association caritative).

Comment: So, what you're basically saying is that *en être à* is an expression there?

Comment: @user69786  Yes it's an expression in so far as *en* and *à* need to be there.  We're dealing with *en être **à*** here (*en être* on its own is different).

Comment: @user69786 "*Sans eux, je ne serais pas arrivé **là** où j'**en** **suis** aujourd'hui*" is one of the prominent examples with the "*en être à*" structure.

Answer (score 4):

> Elle n’**en** est pas à son premier geste.

The sentence means something along the lines of:

> Ce n'est pas la première fois qu'elle fait un don important à la Croix-Rouge japonaise ou à une autre association à but non lucratif.

---

"*Elle*" refers to "*L'actrice américaine Sandra Bullock*". And the word "*geste*" corresponds to "*(a charitable) gesture*" in English -- in the sense of some sort of "*action*".

The pronoun "*en*" is often used to refer back to a "*de ...*" phrase mentioned/implied in the preceding context. To facilitate your understanding of the structure, it can be paraphrased as:

> Elle n’est pas à son premier geste **de** philanthropie envers la Croix-Rouge japonaise
>
> {or}: "... **de** faire un don important"

---

Actually, this sentence does not make sense without "en":

> "Elle n’est pas à son premier geste." -- "De quoi ?"

Answer (score -1):

"Elle" is simply the personal pronoun "she", which stands for "actrice".

At the entry for "en" in the TLFi, in the introduction, you can read this;

> 3. Dans certains cas, en nombre limité, l'antécédent est sous-entendu (implicite) et se dégage de la situation en vertu de l'usage. Dans d'autres cas, **il est réduit à l'emploi d'élément formateur modifiant le sens du verbe** avec lequel il est construit; on présentera cet emploi en entrée distincte. (user **LPH**'s bold type)

This specifies the present use of "en" as we find it in *the fixed locution* "en être à", which is not found in the TLFi and in the Ac. dictionary at the entry for "en", but which corresponds to the division "**II B**" for the entry "en" in the TLFi;

> II. [Dans des loc. figées ou fam., « en » a un antécédent implicite]
>   B. [L'antécédent représente une prop. antécédente, ou une idée parfois vague tirée du cont.]

Here are some of those expressions where the antecedent is vague

*En avoir le cœur net*
*c) S'en tirer, s'en sortir*
*d) En revenir, ne pas en revenir (au fig.)*
*a) En appeler à*
*b) En croire qqn*
*c) [En relation avec un adv. de quantité] En savoir long, en apprendre davantage*
*d) [En relation avec un adv. de lieu] En arriver là, en revenir là*

This is confirmed by the dictionary from the [Ac.](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/EN?options=motExact) (user **LPH**'s bold type);

> IV. Loc. verb. Beaucoup de verbes s'accompagnent du pronom-adverbe « en », et souvent le **sens** de la locution ainsi formée est **plus ou moins éloigné** du sens du verbe simple. Il y a même eu **agglutination** dans des verbes comme « ***enlever*** », « ***s'enfuir*** », « ***s'envoler*** ». À l'origine, « en » avait le sens d'un complément de provenance, de point de départ ou d'un complément de propos. **Dans la plupart des cas**, l'**antécédent est maintenant sous-entendu et vague**, et ne se dégage que du contexte et de la situation. *S'en aller, s'en venir, s'en revenir, s'en retourner, s'en tirer, s'en sortir, en appeler à, s'en prendre à, s'en tenir à, il s'en faut de peu, il s'en faut de beaucoup, en vouloir à, en imposer, en rester à, en finir, en avoir assez, en avoir le cœur net, en savoir long, en user mal avec, en être quitte pour, c'en est fait, vous en avez menti, afin que nul n'en ignore, n'en plus pouvoir, n'en pouvoir mais, savoir ce qu'il en coûte, il en va de même, à en croire, etc. Fam. S'en faire, n'en pas rater une, en voir de toutes les couleurs. Pop. S'en ficher, en baver, s'en donner, en pincer pour, en avoir de bonnes*.

The locution "en être à" is found under "être¹" in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) and is characterised by the following categories;

> 2e Section. Premier élément d'une expression binaire.
>   I. [Affirme ce que quelqu'un ou quelque chose est, dans son essence, sa réalité, son apparence; ou sert à traduire une modalité de jugement sur quelqu'un ou quelque chose]
>   B. [Être est suivi d'un adv., d'une loc. adv., ou d'un syntagme prép.]
>   6. [Pour exprimer l'origine, la provenance, la conformité avec un modèle et p. ext. la caractéristique ou le caractère inhérent à qqn ou qqc., la qualité d'élément ou de membre d'un groupe]
>   e) [Cas partic. de être de **avec pron. adv.** : en être]
>   Autres expr. usuelles. **En être à** ce point; en être réduit au point où j'en suis; il n'(en) est pas où il croit; en être à ses débuts, à sa première affaire, à son premier essai; nous en sommes à l'heure où; (dans un comptage) nous en sommes à cinquante.

The question has been asked already ([The “en” in “je n’en suis pas là”](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36265/17649)), however, this is a special case where the context yields a plausible implicit antecedent; in talking about the reading of a book, the point where "you" are in reading makes sense (one particular point **of** the book) but when refering to an action such a charitable action independently of any context, nothing makes sense;

- Il en était à la première page (du livre, de sa lecture, …)
- Elle en était à la première bonne action (de sa vie ?) Why take specially that person's life as the antecedent? If there had been a self-imposed program of making charitable actions for instance and the person doing that had been in the pocess of carrying out the first one, then there would be an antecedent ("en" could stand for "du programme" or "de ce qu'elle avait décidé" or something similar characterising the background of the action such as "de ce qu'elle avait entrepris"; that shows, incidentally, that all sorts of possibilities are open.

As said in the introduction "en" can be reduced to the role of a building element that modifies the sense of the verb it is used with (translation of the bold type part in the introduction); this is clear now, "en" has vitually the rôle of a preposition in a phrasal verb in the present context; not only is the antecedent  vague as state the dictionaries but it is inexistant; I can assert that not one French locutor is able to identify an antecedent in this present case. The idea of "forming element" that is considered in the introduction of the entry of the TLFi gives that away: that is how locutors aprehend those expressions, never does their thinking rely on the notion of an antecedent in understanding those constructions. You must then take "en être à" as a unit , a set form, and not worry about a special meaning; this is hinted at in the possibility to do away with "en" in one of the expressions above, "il n'en est pas où il croit" or "il n'est pas où il croit".

For instance, in order to characterise a student's progress in his study of mechanics, you can say either of the following;

- Il en  est à l'étude des ressorts. *This answers to the question "Où en est-tu de tes études ?".
- Il est à l'étude des ressorts.

However, the second form is not as  explicit in conferring the idea of progress given by the pronoun (with an implicit antecedent this time, "étude").
If you speak of someone's party life you can't do that, there is no antecedent, the "forming particle" is missing, the verb becomes ambiguous.

- Elle n'en était pas à la première party chez Jean. *This answers to no question; Où en était-elle de [… ?] ?*
- <s>Elle n'était pas à la première party chez Jean.</s>

---

L'actrice américaine Sandra Bullock a fait don d'un million de dollars à la Croix-Rouge nippone. Elle n’en est pas à son premier geste. Sa première donation connue du grand public a été destinée aux familles des victimes et aux survivants de la tragédie du 11 Septembre.

The American actress Sandra Bullock donated a million dollars to the Japanese Red Cross. *That's not the first of her charitable acts.* Her first  widely publicised donation was meant for the families of the victims and survivors in September the 11th's tragedy.