# Why "en" as a pronoun without a "de"?

Tags: grammaire

In an article from RFI, I saw the following sentence:

> Le conflit en est aujourd'hui à son quatrième jour.

I would have expected this to say either *Le conflit est aujourd'hui à son quatrième jour* or *Le conflit est aujourd'hui en son quatrième jour.* I'm not sure which is correct but I would have guessed one of them. But both together? That confuses me. Can anyone explain the role of *en* in this sentence? It seems like it's a pronoun but I don't know what it's there for. I thought *en* as a pronoun was only when *de* was involved.

If context helps, here it is with the preceding sentence:

> Israël a, par ailleurs, déployé des chars et des blindés le long de la frontière avec l'enclave palestinienne de Gaza. Le conflit en est aujourd'hui à son quatrième jour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither *le conflit est aujourd'hui à son quatrième jour* nor *le conflit est aujourd'hui **en** son quatrième jour* are idiomatic. What might have been written is *le conflit est aujourd'hui **dans** son quatrième jour*.

The sentence you read uses the *en être à* construction which has already been discussed here: [Elle n’en est pas à son premier geste - what do "elle" and "en" here refer to?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38087)